# Manipulating the Limit Definition

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to write the definition of $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.
I know the definition of $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ is for all $M<0$ there exists $m>0$ st $x \ge m$ and $x \in D_f$ implies $f(x) \le M$.

How would I manipulate the definition?

Answer (score 1):

You need to express the idea that we can get $f(x)$ larger than any finite bound, as long as we choose $x$ to be closer to $-\infty$.

$\forall M > 0$, there exist $m < 0$ such that $\forall x \in D_f$: $x < m \rightarrow f(x) > M$, assuming that $D_f$ is unbounded below, or I think the limit makes no sense to define.

Comment: It is redundant to require $m<0$.

Comment: True. But the OP had these conditions, so I mimicked his.